# How to calculate after how many years does interest payment equal principal amount?

Tags: functions

I am trying to make a formula to show that for an interest rate of $X \%$, it takes $Y$ years for the annual compound interest to be larger than the original principal amount.

I have come up with the following formula but dont think it is correct,

$Z\text{principal}\cdot\left(1+\dfrac{X}{100}\right)^Y=$ some amount that interest of it is equal to $Z= 100\dfrac{Z}{X}$, so
$$
\begin{split}
\left(\frac{X+100}{100}\right)^Y&=\frac{100}{X}\\
\ln\left(\frac{X+100}{100}\right)^Y&=\ln\frac{100}{X}\\
Y\cdot\ln\left(\frac{X+100}{100}\right)& =\ln\dfrac{100}{X}\\
Y &=\frac{\ln\dfrac{100}{X}}{\ln\left(\frac{X+100}{100}\right)}
\end{split}
$$
Sorry I dont know how to use latex to make the formulae look nice.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: For MathJax support, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I don't understand why you write "interest (...) is equal to $Z=100Z/Y$. What do you mean by this and how did you get this result? It could be a good idea to rewrite the equations so that it's clearer ...

Comment: Hi Matti, i have edited it as that was a mistake.

Comment: For example: if z is 100 and interest is 10% then when the total is 1000 the interest of that 1000 is 100 which is equal to the original principal. How many years will that take? and what formula can be used to work out the number of years(Y) for any interest rate X?

Comment: You seriously need to rewrite a lot of stuff to make this more understandable. I interpret that you want 
$$
\underbrace{Z \left( 1+ \frac{X}{100}\right)^{Y+1}}_{\text{value after Y+1 years}} - \underbrace{Z \left( 1+ \frac{X}{100} \right)^Y}_{\text{value after Y years}} > Z
$$
Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) an try editing your post. Without any improvement, others may not be interested in answering, and the question may get closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake you made was to write that the amount after $y$ years is $100Z/X$. This expressions is rather arbitrary and it does not hold for all combinations of numbers, for the result that you want.

I'll clear up the notation and solve the equation myself. I prefer to use $n$ for the number of years, and I prefer to use $p$ for the percentage factor $p = 1+\frac{X}{100}$. This way, when the interest is, for example $9~\%$, we have $p=1.09$. I think this notation makes the equations much easier.

So in the beginning you have amount (principal) $Z$ which has an interest rate $p$. After $n$ years, the amount is
$$
p^n Z
$$
And after $n+1$ years it's
$$
p^{n+1}Z
$$
You wanted their difference to be larger than the original principal $Z$, or
$$
p^{n+1}Z - p^n Z > Z
$$
It's easy to see that we can divide both sides by $Z$ (we'll assume $Z>0$) to get
$$
p^{n+1} - p^n  > 1 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad p^n (p-1) > 1
$$
From this, it's rather easy to solve for $n$:
$$
p^n > \frac{1}{p-1} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad n \cdot \ln p > -\ln (p-1)
$$
The condition then becomes
$$
n > -\frac{\ln (p-1)}{\ln p}
$$
As a numerical example, if we use the previous example of $9~\%$ interest rate, we get
$ n >27.94$ or 28 years. From this example, we see that actually, we should take the ceiling function of this, because the interest is only given annually. So the most accurate answer would be
$$
n \geq \lceil -\frac{\ln (p-1)}{\ln p} \rceil
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, what do you mean by roof function? does this convert it to whole numbers?Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, it converts a real number into the next whole number that is larger than it. That's because I will assume that interest is only given at the end of the year. If you feel like my answer was helpful and answers the question, feel free to upvote and/or mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I don't recall the name "roof function" but I know "ceiling function".

Comment: @badjohn Thanks, I'll fix it.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, just that I've not heard it.  You could add "also known as".